# Python : issues when loading .mat with scipy.io.loadmat()

Tags: python, scipy, io, load, mat-file

I meet some troubles when I try to laod matlab file (.mat) with scipy (scipy.io.loadmat). The dataset (4 Go) is an output from a wave numerical model (SWAN). The message error is : ValueError: Did not read any bytes
The strange thing is that the .mat is a size of 4 Go. There is probably an explanation but I didn't find it. If someone has an idea...
Here is the code using the mhkit library :

```
def _read_block_mat(swan_file):
'''
Reads in SWAN matlab output and creates a dictionary of DataFrames
for each swan output variable.

Parameters
----------
swan_file: str
    filename to import
    
Returns
-------
dataDict: Dictionary
    Dictionary of DataFrame of swan output variables
'''
assert isinstance(swan_file, str), 'swan_file must be of type str'
assert isfile(swan_file)==True, f'File not found: {swan_file}'
    
dataDict = loadmat(swan_file, struct_as_record=False, squeeze_me=True)
removeKeys = ['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__']
for key in removeKeys:
    dataDict.pop(key, None)
for key in dataDict.keys():
    dataDict[key] = pd.DataFrame(dataDict[key])
return dataDict

def read_block(swan_file):
'''
Reads in SWAN block output with headers and creates a dictionary 
of DataFrames for each SWAN output variable in the output file.

Parameters
----------
swan_file: str
    swan block file to import
    
Returns
-------
data: Dictionary
    Dictionary of DataFrame of swan output variables  
metaDict: Dictionary
    Dictionary of metaData dependent on file type    
'''
assert isinstance(swan_file, str), 'swan_file must be of type str'
assert isfile(swan_file)==True, f'File not found: {swan_file}'

extension = swan_file.split('.')[1].lower()
if extension == 'mat':
    dataDict = _read_block_mat(swan_file)
    metaData = {'filetype': 'mat',
                'variables': [var for var in dataDict.keys()]}
else:
    dataDict, metaData = _read_block_txt(swan_file)
return dataDict, metaData
```

Reading .mat file with the python module scipy (io.loadmat). The fonction doesn't read any bytes but the file is not empty (4Go)

Edouard

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: I wonder if the `.mat` is a newer HDF5 formatted file.  `loadmat` can't load that kind.

Comment: A quick web search on 'SWAN mat file' suggests that there might be a file size issue, https://sourceforge.net/p/swanmodel/mailman/swanmodel-users/thread/CAMNKg6Gk6YsCa9zws_Xg6uLh4JgVqSh0tGLthSZ6a-KKEbn-eQ@mail.gmail.com/

Comment: Thanks hpaulj for your help, I'm now using an another output format and it wworks well.

Answer (score -1):

The file was corrupted.

I had the same problem, it was not an empty file, but it was impossible to open it even in Matlab because the file was corrupted.